# Separating a clause introduced with "such that" by commas

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas, clauses

Consider the following sentence:

> A whatsit such that the condition doodah is fulfilled is called a doodah whatsit.

I am wondering about the placement of commata. Should I add two commata to separate the "such that"-clause?

> A whatsit, such that the condition doodah is fulfilled, is called a doodah whatsit.

What somehow justifies this is that we can rearrange the sentence to read:

> A whatsit is called a doodah whatsit, if the condition doodah is fulfilled.

Suggesting that we have two clauses that should be separated by a comma. But putting a comma before "such that" as in the second sentence looks strange to me.

So, would you place a comma or not? Or is it optional? Or maybe just a single comma before "is"?

Comment: There is a defining role (_such that the condition [Y] is fulfilled_)  and by comparison with defining relative clauses and 'reduced relative clauses' I'd omit commas here. // Using 'commata' rather than the plural form 99+% use marks this question out as less than serious. As do the improbable placeholders.

Comment: I'd recommend a rewrite.

Comment: Just out of interest what made you decide to use the vanishingly rare 'commata' as the plural of 'comma' in place of the overwhelmingly more common 'commas' when you posted this question?

Comment: @BoldBen I am non native and used this intuitively... actually, I cannot give an explanation... maybe because I used the word "lemma" quite often recently, which has the plural "lemmata", but only a guess.

Comment: @StefanH If you're a non-native it's understandable. I'd never heard of the word 'commata' but an online dictionary said that it was an alternative to 'commas'. However an online tool used to count the usage of words in published documents showed that 'commas' was normally used and 'commata' hardly ever. We have a lot of irregular plurals in English so 'commata' was a reasonable guess, it just looks very odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [restrictive clause](https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-9/verbals-and-phrases/lesson-3/restrictive-and-nonrestrictive-participial-phrases) and as such does not get commas.

Your case with the if-clause is a different grammatical structure because the clause does not directly modify the subject.

Comment: That article only deals with restrictive / non-restrictive participial clauses. Another reference, dealing with 'such that ...' clauses is necessary to confirm similar behaviour.